# 'Alternative', 'choice' and 'option'

Tags: word-usage

I was wondering if someone could tell me whether the following sentences mean the same or they have slight nuances:

> - The train was cancelled, so I had no **alternative** but to take a taxi.
> - The train was cancelled, so I had no **choice** but to take a taxi.
> - The train was cancelled, so I had no **option** but to take a taxi.

For me they all mean the same (in this context) and in this sense can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last two sentences, with "choice" and "option", are perfectly fine and equivalent to each other.

I would interpret the first sentence, with "alternative", as equivalent as well.  However, it would not be my first choice of wording.  An *alternative* usually refers to a secondary choice — something less conventional or less preferred.  Since your intention was to catch a train, the taxi *was* your one and only alternative.  In contrast, taking the taxi was one of two choices / options, so "no choice / option but…" feels more justifiable.

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker, I would rate all three as equivalent and appropriate.

Comment: Just one more question; what do you think of changing 'but' to 'except' or 'except for'? The only difference which comes to my mind is that we have to use gerund after 'except for' and apart from this point, they won't make any other nuance or problem in sentence's meaning. Am I right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

In reading the sentences, I was surprised to hear myself prefer "no alternative except", and "no choice but" and "no option but".  Go figure.